# Is using a ControllerServlet good practice for Java EE 6?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I read about ControllerServlet usage in affablebean tutorial for Java EE 6, by Oracle.

It ends up with a servlet handling a lot of different URL requests, like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet",
    loadOnStartup = 1,
    urlPatterns = {
        "/category",
        "/addToCart",
        "/viewCart",
        "/updateCart",
        "/checkout",
        "/purchase",
        "/chooseLanguage"})

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
    @EJB
    private OrderManager orderManager;
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

        // store category list in servlet context
        getServletContext().setAttribute("categories", categoryFacade.findAll());
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();

        // if category page is requested
        if (userPath.equals("/category")) {
            // get categoryId from request
            String categoryId = request.getQueryString();

            if (categoryId != null) {
                // get selected category
                Category selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(Short.parseShort(categoryId));

                 // place selected category in request scope
                 request.setAttribute("selectedCategory", selectedCategory);
                // get all products for selected category
                Collection<Product> categoryProducts = selectedCategory.getProductCollection(); 

                // place category products in request scope
                request.setAttribute("categoryProducts", categoryProducts);
            }

        // if cart page is requested
        } else if (userPath.equals("/viewCart")) {
            // TODO: Implement cart page request

            userPath = "/cart";

        // if checkout page is requested
        } else if (userPath.equals("/checkout")) {
            // TODO: Implement checkout page request

        // if user switches language
        } else if (userPath.equals("/chooseLanguage")) {
            // TODO: Implement language request

        }

        // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
        String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";

        try {
            System.out.println("Redirecting to : "+url);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I wonder if it is good practice for a Java EE project? I'm thinking about adopting Java EE as the framework for a project, which involves a small team of programmers. I think this ControllerServlet is encouraging them to put a lot of business logic inside. The class is expected to grow terribly long with a lot of if/else if... in future.

So what would be your recommendation about such a ControllerServlet to work in a big project?

Comment: Perhaps. Note that this controller is mapping related behaviors.

Comment: Simply because the controller servlet can handle many requests does not make it too big.  The Restlets project uses this model and is very popular.

Comment: you could have linked the tutorial in question as well - would be interested to read about the rationale, if it has it detailed

Comment: also: don't really see actual business logic implemented here. That would be in the EJBs.

Comment: Business logic != servlet mapping strategy. This seems like an awful idea for mapping on a project of any size.

Comment: a beautiful and acceptable way to implement a lot of ifs is using the Command pattern :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that the controller servlet will quickly grow to be unmanageable if you are handling many different actions. You'll wind up with a huge set of **if** or **case** statements following the naive approach you sketched out.

A typical solution would be a front controller pattern that dispatches url mappings to other code that actually handles the requests. There are many relatively straight forward solutions to do this (someone mentioned the command pattern) and it's a key part of most web frameworks. I would probably not write my own front controller in 2016.  What with the ease of standing up annotation based servlets, I would consider  structuring a very simple  application (like a microservice)  around a single action per servlet; handling as many of the http methods as necessary: DELETE, PUT, GET...

However, you are also probably going to need additional features such as templating, reusable UI components, fancy url parameter handling, object to json mapping (and the reverse), sub resource mapping, content negotiation, authorization, etc. To the extent that you do, consider one of the numerous java EE technologies that you can apply to the problem (JAX-RS, JSF,  JSR 371) and even more numerous implementations of each.

If you exposing an api I'd look at a JAX-RS implementation like jersey For a certain kind of application that might suffice: perhaps a single page web application communicating with the back end via ajax calls.You could serve your static content with nginx for apache. For full-blown frameworks you can choose a component based approach that implements the JSF standard or an action based one that implements the mvc1 (JSR 371) spec. You can read about the differences here: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/why_another_mvc_framework_in

You mentioned choosing between JSF and spring mvc,  The former is component based, the latter is action based.  There is currently only one implementation of JSR 371, Ozark, the reference.  If this distinction is important for your choice then you might be hampered by the lack of JSR 371 implementations. But it really does seem to me that the action based approach is the future.

Comment: You can map a servlet with a single annotation; whether or not you need a "framework" depends on what you're actually doing. If all you're doing is dumping JSON to an API consumer then simple mapping and serialization is all you need. Modern JEE is more than enough for lots of projects. (*I* wouldn't use it, but that's just me.)

Comment: so you don't think servlet/ejb:s are made "for" this, especially the new ones? I think I have to disagree here.

Comment: I'm just looking at the sample code posted. You are going to want to dispatch those url endpoints to other code. Perhaps the ejb route provides a nice way to do that. It seems heavy handed to me.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Yes, the way this is set up with multiple URLs going to the same servlet is wonky. But the JEE framework already handles rational mapping via the same annotation mechanism. Just because you *can* do it wrong doesn't mean you *must*, or that it's unsuitable for modern development.

Comment: I have amended my answer to make clearer that my criticism was only about implementing your own front controller to handle many different actions with one servlet.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I've come to the realization that I should either adopt Spring MVC or JSF. As I intend to entirely obey the JAVA EE design, I would go for JSF.

Comment: Consider a more modern approach than JSF. Component based frameworks are very heavy weight. Take a look at something like thymeleaf or pebble for templating.